# SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type when update the latest sherlock library in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

when I use sherlock library 4.2.0.0 in my android apps my apps working fine and update the sherlock library with 4.4.0.0 then my apps working fine but when upgrade eclipse and android sdk then got error "**SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type**" and other classes and methods of sherlock giving a same error "**--- cannot be resolved to a type**" .
When i upgrade my eclipse i saw some changes in folder structure and showing error under
"**Android Private Libraries**" folder like "missing" something.

some people suggest me delete the android-support-v4.jar from libs because this already present in "Android Private Libraries" then i deleted. when the build the all android projects then I got error "error while execute aapt.exe" on popup . I don't know why this
happen.  
Que.1 is there any file missing while i am updating eclipse.

I did add library like a,
create new android project -> make it library without creating activity -> after that ->
import the sherlock library into that project. 
and add this library to the my android apps 
project properties -> add sherlock libary

I am also upgrade eclipse and sdk. I tried lot of way to add the sherlock library but not added yet. please suggest me some solution because i want to deploy my apps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with Sherlock and it was Compiler compliance setting that I had to set to 1.6.

Try with Right click on you project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level and set 1.6

Comment: Compiler compliance level already set 1.6. can i set to Compiler compliance level to 1.7 then is it work?

Comment: I could not do that. In 1.7 I had a lo of issue, that's why I was telling you to check it.

Comment: can you tell me some another way?

Comment: I'm sorry, you will have to wait for someone having a clue/answer